# OkHttpClient не делает запрос

Tags: java, android, json, okhttp

Пытаюсь отправить json и получить json с OkHttpClient.В начале все работало но после создания еще объектов этого класса в других активностях запрос не уходит.Почти сразу же вырубается.

```
class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        String str = null;
        JSONObject json=null;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Main2Activity.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Проверка данных...");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Ждите...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Void... voids) {

            OkHttpClient client = SingletonOkHttp.getClient();

            try {
                json = new JSONObject("{'name':'"+sname+"','password':'"+snumber+"'}");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"),json.toString());
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://url")
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                str = response.body().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void aVoid) {
            if(str!=null){
                try {
                json = new JSONObject(str.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                str = json.getString("result");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if(str.equals("200")){
             //тут еще пара вещей
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Введенные данные не корректны", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }}else{
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Сервер не отвечает либо проблема со связью",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            return;
        }
    }
```

build.gradle.xml

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kg.com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'

}
```

Comment: Логи-то есть какие-нибудь?

Comment: `после создания еще объектов этого класса в других активностях запрос не уходит` -- асинстаски нынче по дефолту выполняются параллельно.

Comment: `Main2Activity.this` -- в соответствующих классах попробуйте передавать соответствующий контекст.

Comment: @post_zeev спасибо.все заработало.Только все протестил в эмуляторе.

Comment: в мобилке ничего не работает по прежнему.Похоже проблема в нем.